# Regex for float that allows negative and single . and -

Tags: javascript, regex, floating-point

I'm currently working in a input validator and I'm having some problem with the regex.

Every time the text changes the regex is tested and if it fails the last change will be ignored.

I need standard numbers, both int and float. Positive and negative as well as single "." and single "-".
Empty string should also be valid.

I've created this fiddle with my valid and invalid cases:
https://jsfiddle.net/rrjfkjvz/1/

```
var regex = /[-+]?\d*\.?\d*/;

console.log("ok");
console.log(regex.test(""));
console.log(regex.test("."));
console.log(regex.test(".1"));
console.log(regex.test("1.1"));
console.log(regex.test("-"));
console.log(regex.test("-1"));
console.log(regex.test("0"));
console.log(regex.test("1"));
console.log(regex.test("-."));
console.log(regex.test("-.1"));
console.log(regex.test("-1."));
console.log(regex.test("-1.1"));

console.log("fail");
console.log(regex.test(".."));
console.log(regex.test("--"));
console.log(regex.test("-1-"));
console.log(regex.test(".1."));
console.log(regex.test("a"));
console.log(regex.test("_"));
console.log(regex.test("?"));
```

Comment: Can you add the regex you are currently using to the question content?

Comment: @Tushar Doesn't match `-`.

Comment: @Tushar Now it matches an empty string. Not sure if OP wants that (*because the question is incomplete!*).

Comment: Well, I'm also not quite sure what OP wants. Just guesses.

Comment: Matching of empty string is fine, but now it matches everything for me. I've updated my initial post with a fiddle to show by desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you provided in the jsfiddle, you just need to modify it slightly.

I changed your regex from `/[-+]?\d*\.?\d*/` to `/^[-+]?\d*\.?\d*$/`. Using the new regex, it'll pass all of the passing tests you supplied (and fail all the tests you marked as fail).

The only thing i did was add the `^` and `$` to specify we want this to match the entire string supplied (start to end).

In your version of the regex, it was doing more of a contains instead of an equals. It was just trying to match the regex pattern within the string, it didn't matter if there was unused characters within the string.

Comment: Ah I totally forgot about the start and end parameters. I'm quite new to regex so not everything is crystal yet. Thanks a lot! :)